# Remote Media Player HTTP response handling

Tags: android, error-handling, google-api, xmlhttprequest, chromecast

I'm using the Receiver API When building a chromecast receiver. Since playing of the media requires certain authentication token that is only valid for a short period of time (say 5 minutes). If the users decide to play content that lasts longer than 5 minutes, the source will likely respond with an HTTP error code once the time frame has passed. In this case, I would like there to be a way to retrieve the error code so I can re-authenticate on the device end. So I was wondering if there's any receiver API(error handling callbacks) that supports this model?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Media Player Library (MPL), then you can use the [RequestStatus](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.RequestStatus) class to see the error code, status, response headers, and response body for the failed license request.

Comment: Ah ok, completely missed this one! Thanks!